# Rails serialize vs polymorphic associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, data-modeling, polymorphic-associations

I was watching RailsCast 403 (dynamic forms) and noted that Ryan mentioned that serialize with a hash could be an alternative to having multiple tables with associations but didn't go into any detail with it (I assume this would be through polymorphic associations). I couldn't find any other blogs or posts on this so either I'm asking a ridiculous question or I'm missing something obvious.

Essentially the RailsCast goes through having a table with common fields (ie. product_nam, product_price and product_type) and then having a serialized hash stored for the different types of products (ie. a product of type shirt would have attributes size and colour stuffed into a hash and then stored into a single field in the table).

I think this could also be done through polymorphic associations (ie. having a separate table for each different product type). The benefit with polymorphic associations is that it would likely be easier to search and sort the data if it was standardized in a table.

Are there other advantages to structuring data in a serialized vs a polymorphic approach? Is one more conventional than the other? I'm tempted to use serialization as I could essentially re-purpose a lot of the code in that RailsCast, but I want to make sure I'm not missing something really obvious.